# exclude a subdomain from a dns wildcard record

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, wildcards

I have a domain name set with wildcard for all subdomain (*.mydomain.com), I need of exclude a specific subdomain from this condition, I use a record dns for set wildcard and if I set a new record A for a specific subdomain it not work

Comment: What DNS server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When I have a \* entry in my zone file, how can I treat a specific name as nonexistent?](http://serverfault.com/questions/586100/when-i-have-a-entry-in-my-zone-file-how-can-i-treat-a-specific-name-as-nonexi)

Answer (score 11):

Normally when you define a wildcard record, it will only match if no other record matches. So if you have

```
example.com.        A 8.9.10.11
*.example.com.      A 4.5.6.7
host1.example.com.  A 1.2.3.4
```

A wild card will only be matched if there is no subdomain defined. If you ask host1.example.com. it should return 1.2.3.4  and not 4.5.6.7

If this is the case, it might be that the changes haven't propagated yet. Use the `dig` to query your DNS server and some public server (google's is 8.8.8.8).

Comment: I use plesk installed on debian distribution, this is dns zone of the domain name: <pre>*.mydomain.it. CNAME mydomain.it.
XXX.XXX.86.76 / 24 PTR mydomain.it.
mydomain.it. NS ns.mydomain.it.
mydomain.it. NS wordpress.mydomain.it.
mydomain.it. A XXX.XXX.86.76
mydomain.it. MX (10) mail.mydomain.it.
mydomain.it. TXT v=spf1 +a +mx -all
ftp.mydomain.it. CNAME mydomain.it.
mail.mydomain.it. A XXX.XXX.86.76
ns.mydomain.it. A XXX.XXX.86.76
wordpress.mydomain.it. A YYY.YYY.187.230</pre> in this example the subdomain wordpress.mydomain.it work on documentroot of main domain and not on YYY.YYY.187.230

Comment: @Alessio Does it return the correct address when you query that name with `dig` or `nslookup`?