# When I have a * entry in my zone file, how can I treat a specific name as nonexistent?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, outlook

On our main domain, `example.com` we're hosting a lot of websites. So we just added a `*` A/AAAA record to our zone and pointed it at our webserver.

Sadly, this also causes Outlook to constantly hammer our webserver, because now `autodiscover.example.com` points at our webserver. Not only will Outlook constantly try to connect to it, it will also pop open a warning, that the SSL certificate served by `autodiscover.example.com` isn't valid for that domain.

To counter that issue, I added an explicit `autodiscover` A record and pointed it to `127.0.0.1`, but that just causes *other* issues (especially when I'm running a webserver locally).

So, ideally, I would want to mark `autodiscover` as nonexistent, so that Outlook will skip to a different auto-discovery mechanism. I realize that I could simply maintain a proper list of valid names in our zone, but I was hoping for something that requires less maintenance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can’t set a node name to not resolve, unfortunately. However, as you discovered, if there is a node name defined for `autodiscover`, that definition will take precedence over the wildcard record.

What you can do is to set up a definition for `autodiscover`, but not as an A/CNAME record. Try. for example, a TXT record instead. From your DNS server’s point of view, the node is defined which means it won’t match the wildcard. From Outlook’s point of view, there is no A record so it can’t be resolved.

This is, of course, provided Outlook behaves sensibly and asks only for A/AAAA. I would not lay any money on that, but it’s worth a try.

Comment: According to the Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer, this resolved the issue: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rav3Y.png Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it works!